# RightNow SSO using SAML 2.0 with OIM/OIF

Tags: saml-2.0, rightnow-crm

I'm currently stuck in implementing SSO in RightNow using SAML 2.0.From what I have read in the RightNow documents, it supports SAML 2.0 but with little caveats like, sending the signing certificate with the SAML response and not supporting importing the metadata into RightNow.
I'm integrating RightNow with Oracle Identity Federation (11.1.1.6) and am a little stuck with the way forward. Ideally while integrating an application for SSO, we have the metadata that helps in setting the Service Provider (this is ideally an application that requires the SSO service). But I am unable to figure out how to set RightNow application as a Service Provider in the absence of a Provider Metadata! Is there a way in RightNow to generate and download the metadata!? If not, how to go about configuring it? Are there any examples you can point me to that showcase how to do it?

Appreciate your time and effort guys. Thank you in advance.

@Andy - the metadata file

```
<md:EntityDescriptor xmlns:md="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:metadata" xmlns:saml="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:assertion" xmlns:ds="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#" entityID="https://myorg--test.custhelp.com/fed/sp" validUntil="2023-05-07T16:44:40.193Z">
    <ds:Signature></ds:Signature>
    <md:SPSSODescriptor WantAssertionsSigned="false" AuthnRequestsSigned="false" protocolSupportEnumeration="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:protocol">
        <md:KeyDescriptor use="signing">
            <ds:KeyInfo>
                <ds:X509Data>
                    <ds:X509Certificate>X509_CERTIFICATE</ds:X509Certificate>
                    <ds:X509IssuerSerial>
                        <ds:X509IssuerName>
                            X509_ISSUER_NAME</ds:X509IssuerName>
                        <ds:X509SerialNumber>X509_SERIAL_NUMBER</ds:X509SerialNumber>
                    </ds:X509IssuerSerial>
                    <ds:X509SubjectName>X509_SUBJECT_NAME</ds:X509SubjectName>
                </ds:X509Data>
            </ds:KeyInfo>
            <md:EncryptionMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2001/04/xmlenc#rsa-1_5"/>
            <md:EncryptionMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2001/04/xmlenc#aes128-cbc"/>
            <md:EncryptionMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2001/04/xmlenc#aes192-cbc"/>
            <md:EncryptionMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2001/04/xmlenc#aes256-cbc"/>
            <md:EncryptionMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2001/04/xmlenc#tripledes-cbc"/>
        </md:KeyDescriptor>
        <md:NameIDFormat>urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:nameid-format:unspecified</md:NameIDFormat>
        <md:AssertionConsumerService Binding="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:bindings:HTTP-POST" Location="https://myorg--test.custhelp.com/cgi-bin/myorg.cfg/php/admin/sso_launch.php?p_subject=Account.Login" index="0" isDefault="true"/>
            <md:AttributeConsumingService index="0" isDefault="true">
                <md:ServiceName xml:lang="en">https://myorg--test.custhelp.com/cgi-bin/myorg.cfg/php/admin/sso_launch.php</md:ServiceName>
                    <md:RequestedAttribute Name="uid" isRequired="true"/>
            </md:AttributeConsumingService>
    </md:SPSSODescriptor>
    <md:Organization>
        <md:OrganizationName xml:lang="en">My Organization RightNow Customer Experience Site</md:OrganizationName>
        <md:OrganizationDisplayName xml:lang="en">My Organization RightNow Customer Experience</md:OrganizationDisplayName>
        <md:OrganizationURL xml:lang="en">http://www.my-org.com</md:OrganizationURL>
    </md:Organization>
</md:EntityDescriptor>
```

Upon hitting the SSO URL in Oracle RightNow, I do not get a response back. I verified this using the SAML tracer plug-in for FireFox and also there is no error code returned. I have also configured the SAML_ERROR_URL with %error_code% and %session% variable.
The X509 certificate has been uploaded to RightNow and USE_KNOWN_ROOT_CAS has been set.

My hunch is that the end-point URL has something to do with it. Where to move forward from here?
Again, thanks for your help Andy.

Comment: Am I the only one facing this issue or this is not the right forum?

Answer (score 2):

RightNow + SAML is a pain, impossible to debug, but possible to do. After much trial and error I've been able to get it to work with OIF in the past.

There should be a manual way to create a service provider in OIF. RightNow doesn't have any way to generate the OIF metadata automatically, but here is a stub that you can use as a start point. There are a few replacement's you'll need to make for your specific site:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?><md:EntityDescriptor xmlns:md="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:metadata" xmlns:ds="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#" entityID="RightNow-Site" validUntil="2023-05-07T16:44:40.193Z">
   <md:SPSSODescriptor WantAssertionsSigned="true" protocolSupportEnumeration="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:protocol">
      <md:KeyDescriptor use="signing">
         <ds:KeyInfo>
            <ds:X509Data>
               <ds:X509Certificate>YOUR_PUBLIC_CERT_HERE</ds:X509Certificate>
            </ds:X509Data>
         </ds:KeyInfo>
      </md:KeyDescriptor>
      <md:NameIDFormat>urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:1.1:nameid-format:unspecified</md:NameIDFormat>
      <md:AssertionConsumerService Binding="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:bindings:HTTP-POST" Location="https://my-url.custhelp.com/cgi-bin/my-interface.cfg/php/admin/sso_launch.php?p_subject=Account.Login" index="0" isDefault="true"/>
      <md:AttributeConsumingService index="0" isDefault="true">
         <md:ServiceName xml:lang="en">MY_SERVICE_NAME</md:ServiceName>
         <md:RequestedAttribute Name="mail" isRequired="true"/>
      </md:AttributeConsumingService>
   </md:SPSSODescriptor>
</md:EntityDescriptor>
```

Other notes from my previous attempts:

- The Cert usages on your signing cert seem to matter. I was never certain which usages were required by RN, but it did seem to play a factor
- The metadata above assumes you are using Login as your NamedID. You can change this per the RN instructions

Comment: This is of huge help. Many Thanks Andy for the guidance. I will come back with the result shortly.

Comment: with your inputs I created the Metadata file for RightNow but I'm still not there. Please see my edits for the metadata file contents and configuration that I did at RightNow side.

Comment: To confirm, you are trying to do Agent Console SSO and not Customer Portal SSO. If so, there will be no redirect to an error page. You will just see a page called Access Denied.

Also, you are not simply hitting the SSO endpoint in the browser and expecting a redirect to your Identity Provider, right? The RN SSO endpoint only accepts unsolicited responses (i.e., you have to post the SAML token immediately).

Also, you have populated your uid value into the RightNow Account login field?

Comment: Yes Andy, I'm trying to do SSO for Agent Console not Customer Portal. I'm not hitting the SSO endpoint directly rather the Identity Provider's login screen comes whenever the RightNow URL is hit [link](https://sso.myorg.com/fed/idp/initiatesso?providerid=https://myorg--test.custhelp.com/fed/sp) where the value of providerid is the EntityID in RightNow metadata. The UID is populated in Account.Login field too. I can also see that my Identity provider creates & posts SAML content with X509 certificate but nothing happens at RightNow. All I get is "SSO Login failed" on the browser.

Comment: Ok. That all sounds correct. Remember how I said originally that RN + SAML is a pain? ;)  Next thing to look at is your cert format. The type of extension you use is important depending on if it's DER encoded or PEM encoded. If it's PEM the extension needs to be .pem. If it's DER, the extension must be .crt.
Also, did you remember to set the SAML_20_SIGN_CERTS setting in RN with your cert's thumbprint?

Comment: I totally agree that its a pain :(. I will look into this cert format from the beginning ensuring nothing is left untouched. Will update in a day or two on this. Thanks Andy.

Comment: Its been quite some time. I got the cert and other things all set but it didn't work. It turns out that RightNow expects the Account.Login value to be populated in the saml:NameID tag, which is not happening for some reason from my OIF 11gR1. I've done all the changes but still its passing the encrypted value instead of plaintext Account.Login.
I'm going to look into OIF and how SAML2.0 as IdP is implemented and will update once I have the solution.
Thanks Andy for the helpful response and as you rightly said, "its a real pain to configure it :D" but I feel it just a few correct clicks away.

Comment: Sounds like the issue here was the iDP and not Service Cloud...even though Andy is right that it can be difficult to troubleshoot these errors with Service Cloud.  I'd vote that you give Andy that answer checkbox for the points since you found the source of the issue.